# Xcode10.1 RestKit error _$s7RestKit11DynamicKeysVN

Tags: swift, xcode, restkit

I am coming from a different coding language/tools and I am trying to learn xcode/swift. Sorry if this is a simple question.
I was following some youtube video on making an app.

I added a few pods, including one called RestKit to my project. When I tried to build, I didn't get any errors from building but I get this error when the app tries to start.

I have look around google/youtube but I didn't find an answer about this problem. Is it some kind of framework that is missing?

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _$s7RestKit11DynamicKeysVN
Referenced from: /Users/name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/60B44AFB-0BDB-434F-AB6C-FE1A776BC530/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BE8BA7CA-E518-42F7-A035-A5F5E440DEA5/MyApp.app/Frameworks/Assistant.framework/Assistant
Expected in: /Users/name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/60B44AFB-0BDB-434F-AB6C-FE1A776BC530/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BE8BA7CA-E518-42F7-A035-A5F5E440DEA5/MyApp.app/Frameworks/RestKit.framework/RestKit
in /Users/name/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/60B44AFB-0BDB-434F-AB6C-FE1A776BC530/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BE8BA7CA-E518-42F7-A035-A5F5E440DEA5/MyApp.app/Frameworks/Assistant.framework/Assistant
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you open the workspace to build the application?

If that doesn't work try running `pod update` then try opening your .xcworkspace file and running it again.

[Update]

The error is looking for Assistant.framework in the app. Make sure it's being copied into the app.

If you dissect the path you'll see that it says coresimulator/devices/.../appname.app, which is the path to the simulator. The rest is the path to the framework. If you go to the path it probably won't be there. You might want to keep a finder window open to that path to check to see if your build ever copies the files to it's proper path.

Do the following to copy the file over.

Select your project -> your target -> build phases
Then check for a copy files phase, it could be renamed to be something else, and add the framework. Also make sure the destination is set to frameworks.

If you don't have that copy files phase then you'll need to add it.
Select the '+' at the top of the build phases screen
Then add the new copy files phase
Select frameworks as the destination, because that's what the error wants and then add the proper frameworks. Try assistant framework first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using workspace and I tried pod update which didnt fix my problem.

Comment: I tried building and I'm already getting errors. It also looks like the latest build is failing.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Did you try copying those items into your buid?

Comment: Im sorry I am new to xcode, how do I copy the pods to my build?

Comment: Check out the Update I added to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I follow the path and I do have the file Assistant.framework. 

For my project I have ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/IBMWatsonAssistantV1/Assistant.framework and ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/IBMWatsonAssistantV2/Assistant.framework which I installed (I installed IBM waston too)do I need something like restkit/Assistant.framework or something?

Is this correct?
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/Assistant.framework

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same page, inside your appName.app package you have a framework directory with both the Assistant.framework and the Restkit.framework files in them?

Comment: Those paths you gave me, I don't know what they're for.

Comment: This is what I have inside my app when I click on show package contents

https://i.imgur.com/oQBs8Sq.png

This is my xcode build phase with my app target selected
https://i.imgur.com/Xqyjb3V.png
https://i.imgur.com/d5omduT.png

Comment: All your framework files are in at the base of your app rather in the framework directory. The error says "pathToApp/MyApp.app/Frameworks/Assistant.framework/Assistant" you've shown me that the contents are in "pathToApp/MyApp.app/Assistant.framework/Assistant"

Comment: Have you tried to add a copy phase? I have directions to do so in my answer.